# Como capturar datos de un select dinámico

Tags: html, jquery

Tengo un formulario sencillo, con el cual, a partir de unos datos realizo un cálculo. Ahora le he agregado la opción de esos datos y el resultado mandarlos por mail.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Según la cantidad de menores que se ingresen, necesito conocer las edades de cada uno de ellos. A continuación el código para crear estos selects dinámicos:

```
    var hijos = 0;
//var optsel = "<option></option>";
 $('#cantme').on('keyup',function(){
    hijos = $("#cantme").val();
            if ( hijos > 0 ) {
            //  alert("hay " + hijos + "menores");
            for( i = 1; i <= hijos ; i++ ){
                $("#cantMenores").append('<div class="col-md-3" class="cant-menores"><select class="input-sm" name="edadMenores_'+i+'" id ="edadMenores_'+i+'"><option value="">Edad del menor '+i+'</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option></select></div>');
                }

            }  })
```

Al momento de mandar el mail, tengo lo siguiente:

```
function submitForm(){

    var nombre = $("#nombre").val();
    var correo = $("#correo").val();
    var desti = $("#destinos option:selected").html();
    //var message = $("#message").val();
    var cantHab = $("#canthabitaciones").val();
    var cantAdu = $("#cantiacompa").val();
    var cantMen = $("#cantme").val();
    //var edadMenor = //$('#edadMenores_1').serialize();
    /*var edadMenor = [];
        if( cantMen > 0 ){
            for (var i; i <= cantMen; i++) {
                edadMenor = $('#edadMenores_1').val();
                alert(edadMenor);
            }
        }*/
    //alert(edadMenor);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "procesa-simulador.php",
        data: {nombre: nombre, correo: correo, cantHab: cantHab, cantAdu: cantAdu, cantMen: cantMen, desti: desti},
        success : function(text){
            if (text == "success"){
                formSuccess();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

(Lo comentado son pruebas que he realizado)
¿Cómo puedo hacer para enviar estos datos por mail?
O sea, por ejemplo, si cantidad de menores es 0, manda 0 (con esta opción no tengo problema). Si cantidad de menores es 3, mandaría:
Cantidad de Menores = 3
"Menor 1" - 3 años
"Menor 2" - 6 años
"Menor 3" - 1 años

***Aclaración***: sacando esta duda, el mail lo envía perfectamente.
Así llega el mail en este momento (cuando no hay menores ;) ):
Nombre: Aguilera, Juan
Email: solpropyme@gmail.com
Destino: Córdoba 
Cantidad de Habitaciones: 1
Cantidad de Adultos: 3
**Cantidad de Menores: 0**

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estabas un poco cerca de lograr capturar la edad de los menores de forma correcta, solo debemos recorrer la cantidad de `select` que se hayan generado y a cada uno capturarle su `name` (que lo usaremos para saber cual menor es) y su valor, ambos datos los agregaremos a un `array` como un objeto, cuyas propiedades serán `menor` y `edad` generando finalmente un `array de objetos`.

He intentado generar tu formulario en el ejemplo y también es bueno que tengas en cuenta que el resto de campos que tenías los he omitido, ya tu los puedes volver a agregar.

Te dejo el ejemplo funcional con un `console.log()` donde te muestro al final como se ha generado el `array de objetos` que contiene las edades de los menores.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var hijos = 0;
    
    $('#cantme').on('keyup',function(){
        hijos = $("#cantme").val();

        $("#cantMenores").html('');

        if ( hijos > 0 ) {
            for( i = 1; i <= hijos ; i++ ){
                $("#cantMenores").append('<div class="col-md-3"><div class="form-group"><select class="input-sm" name="edadMenor_'+i+'" id ="edadMenor_'+i+'"><option value="">Edad del menor '+ i +'</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option></select></div></div>');
            }
        }
    });

    $("#formulario").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var cantAdu = $("#cantiacompa").val();
        var cantMen = $("#cantme").val();

        var edadesMenores = [];

        $("#cantMenores select").each(function(index, dato){
            edadesMenores.push({'menor':$(dato).attr('name'), 'edad':$(dato).val()});
        });

        console.log('Cantidad adultos: ' + cantAdu + ' Cantidad menores: ' + cantMen);
        console.log(edadesMenores);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "procesa-simulador.php",
            data: {cantAdu: cantAdu, cantMen: cantMen, edadesMenores: JSON.stringify(edadesMenores)},

            success : function(text){
                if (text == "success"){
                    formSuccess();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <form id="formulario" method="" action="#">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Cantidad de adultos*</label>
            <input type="text" name="cantiacompa" id="cantiacompa" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Cantidad de menores*</label>
            <input type="text" name="cantme" id="cantme" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div id="cantMenores" class="col-md-12"></div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="calcular">Calcular</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="borrar">Borrar</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

En este ejemplo funcional te muestro como capturar los datos y enviarlos al archivo **PHP**, recuerda que he omitido otros datos que tenías solo para generar este ejemplo pero tu puedes volverlos a agregar tal y como los tenías, ahora te mostraré como deberás recibir en `PHP` ese `array de objetos` que hemos enviado:

```
$cantAdu = $_POST['cantAdu'];
$cantMen = $_POST['cantMen'];
$edadesMenores = json_decode($_POST['edadesMenores']);
```

Una vez que recibas `edadesMenores` de esta forma podrás manipularlos como un objeto, podrás recorrerlos en un `foreach` o emplear tu lógica para procesar los datos:

```
foreach($edadesMenores as $key => $edad){
    echo($edad->menor . ' ' . $edad->edad);
}
```

Comment: Camilo. Al final de la pregunta agregué algo que sucede ahora. Una parte funcionó perfecto, pero ahora falla el envío o el retorno de la respuesta

Comment: @SolucionesPyMESyHogares debes crear otra pregunta para eso por que ya parece que el problema viene siendo el PHP al retornar los datos y no el JS al enviarlos, te invito a que finalicemos esta pregunta aceptando la respuesta crees la nueva y busquemos la solución a tu nuevo problema, saludos!